# Output a record that appears more than x times

Tags: sql

I am a beginner in SQL, and I need help to get the solution for this condition.

Output the name of any person who bought tickets to visit the Park more than 4 days in a single month. (Also, output the month.)

```
create table visitor( 
visitID         char(n),
name            char(n) not null,
primary key (visitID)
);

create table ticket(
ticketID        char(n),
ticketType      char(n),
day             int(n),
month           char(n),
year            int(n),
visitID         char(n),
primary key (ticketID), foreign key (visitID) references visitor
);
```

I am unable to test my code, but what I have so far is

```
SELECT name, month
FROM Visitor NATURAL JOIN Ticket AS t
JOIN (SELECT name, month
    FROM Visitor NATURAL JOIN Ticket 
    GROUP BY month, year
    HAVING COUNT(1) > 4
) AS s
ON t.name = s.name AND t.month = s.month;
```

I don't know if this is right or not.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT s.name, t.month
FROM Visitor inner JOIN Ticket AS t
ON t.visitID= s.visitID
group by month, year
having count(day)>4
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query may be right technically.  But the subquery answers your question:

```
SELECT name, month
FROM Visitor NATURAL JOIN Ticket 
GROUP BY month, year
HAVING COUNT(1) > 4;
```

Two points, though.  Don't use `natural join`.  It can do strange things, based on the names of columns in the table.  Explicitly name the columns, using `on` or `using`.  And, in some databases, `month` and `year` might be reserved words.  So they are bad names for columns.  You can quote them (in most databases) with double quotes.  So:

```
SELECT "month", "year"
FROM Visitor INNER JOIN
     Ticket 
     using (VisitorId)
GROUP BY "month", "year"
HAVING COUNT(1) > 4;
```

The query might need to count distinct dates.  In this case, the `having` clause should be:

```
HAVING count(distinct "day") > 4
```

Comment: So how would the entire query look? Sorry, I'm new to SQL so I'm still kind of confused.

Comment: It never ceases to amaze me what kinds of suggested edits get rubber-stamped. Someone gratuitously makes the formatting *less* standard and *reduces* readability, and it gets approved 3-0. :|

Comment: @AdiInbar . . . There is no standard formatting.  I have my own style, which I am very particular about, and I generally resent it when someone (like the original changer, not you) undoes the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I have just started learning Mysql. I am still going through the basic syntax and everything so cant really help. But don't you think there is a fault in your question. As Name attribute in the visitor table is not unique(and it should not even be unique). So basically your not finding the same person. Your just trying to find different person that have the same name that visited the park 4 times in a month.